# loading extjs bar chart sample into a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, charts, extjs4.2

Just a newbie here trying to understand and work on extjs 4.2.1. I really like the charts and grids and wanted to incorporate them into my current application. I got the sample grid to work in my application but the chart turns out to be a little harder. I used the sample code at

[sample code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/charts/Bar.html)

which renders the chart in another window and was wondering if someone can help me put this into a div tag on one of my panels.

Here is the container I have for the chart:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:false">
         <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

and the chart script: charts.js

```
Ext.require('Ext.chart.*');
```

Ext.require(['Ext.Window', 'Ext.fx.target.Sprite', 'Ext.layout.container.Fit']);

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var textArea;

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: ['name', 'visits', 'views'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Jul 07', visits: 245000, views: 3000000 },
        { name: 'Aug 07', visits: 240000, views: 3500000 },
        { name: 'Sep 07', visits: 355000, views: 4000000 },
        { name: 'Oct 07', visits: 375000, views: 4200000 },
        { name: 'Nov 07', visits: 490000, views: 4500000 },
        { name: 'Dec 07', visits: 495000, views: 5800000 },
        { name: 'Jan 08', visits: 520000, views: 6000000 },
        { name: 'Feb 08', visits: 620000, views: 7500000 }
    ]
});
```

Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.CustomBlue', {
        extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Base',

```
    constructor: function (config) {
        var titleLabel = {
            font: 'bold 18px Arial'
        }, axisLabel = {
            fill: 'rgb(8,69,148)',
            font: '12px Arial',
            spacing: 2,
            padding: 5
        };

        this.callParent([Ext.apply({
            axis: {
                stroke: '#084594'
            },
            axisLabelLeft: axisLabel,
            axisLabelBottom: axisLabel,
            axisTitleLeft: titleLabel,
            axisTitleBottom: titleLabel
        }, config)]);
    }
});

var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    store: store,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data1'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Number of Hits',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['name'],
        title: 'Month of the Year'
    }],
    theme: 'CustomBlue',
    background: {
        gradient: {
            id: 'backgroundGradient',
            angle: 45,
            stops: {
                0: {
                    color: '#ffffff'
                },
                100: {
                    color: '#eaf1f8'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + ' views');
            }
        },
        label: {
            display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'data1',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: ['data1']
    }]
      renderTo: "container"
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain what the problem was, however it's pretty clear from looking at the code.

The issue is that you need to give the chart a width/height, because it needs those to size appropriately. In the original example in the docs, the dimensions are provided explicitly by the `fit` layout used on the window.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes I did not clarify, that I was not seeing the chart. Once I added the  height: 350,
        width: 800, I can see the chart just not the bars and data; so I will work on that a bit before accepting your answer. Really appreciate your response.

Comment: The fields in your chart definition `data1` don't match what's in the store.

Comment: Yep, got it to work, thanks. By the way do you perhaps know of a link that illustrates getting data from a remote source and passing it to these kinds of widgets, charts/grids in extjs. I will leave you alone now and thanks again.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of examples. `grep` the examples directory for calls to `.load()` on a store.